# Compression issues with JQuery file in YUI Compressor

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression, yui

I am trying to minify a few files with YUI compressor. However, I seem to be getting an error on 2 lines of code, which prevents compression.  The .js file for [jcarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) contains 1 error, and my own code contains the other.

I have narrowed it down and in both occasions it looks like the the float property used in jQuery is causing this. The line is:

```
li.css({overflow: "hidden", float: o.vertical ? "none" : "left"}); (jcarousellite)

$("#now-playing .js-kit-rating div:first").css({width: "80px", float: "right"}).addClass("clearing"); (own code)
```

A working example of the error can be seen by running the [jCarouselLite code](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js) through the YUI compressor, but basically the error returned is invalid property id.

Has anyone had similar issues with the YUI compressor?

Comment: Sounds like you need to be running Firefox and the Firebug JS debugger, it should catch things like this, maybe.

Answer (score 59):

It's not YUI per se, it's the jcarouselLite js. "float" is a reserved word. It needs to be put in quotes. EG:

```
li.css({overflow: "hidden", "float": o.vertical ? "none" : "left"});
```

Similar issue with your own code. YUI is trying its best to compile that js but will refuse/warn you of code like the one you found. IMO it's doing the right thing.

Comment: to be accurate, float is not a reserved word in javascript, but YUI flags it because it is a "possible future keywords by the ECMAScript specification."

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that `var coordinates = { long: 0, lat: 0 };` was a problem (long reserved word). Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I've run into this issue a few times with the word "class". If you're using YUI on the server side, it should spit out the line number it's complaining about.

Here's a list of reserved words that seems pretty comprehensive.

http://mattsnider.com/languages/javascript/reserved-words-in-javascript/

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here answer the actual problem (reserved words). But I am using YUI via [BundleTransformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/) and it isn't outputting line numbers, so I was a little lost as to where to look.

To speed up the process of finding the keywords I went looking for another tool.

**[This online YUI compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/) helped me find the problematic property name.**

Answer (score 0):

in my case when YUI was unable to compress my files it was because I had the 'debugger' in the js file. Hope this saves someone else several hours of debugging!

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a custom version for update yui compressor

https://github.com/MrD0llaro/yuicompressor
and 
https://github.com/MrD0llaro/yui-compressor-ant-task/
for use it on new Jquery 3.5.1